# Coordinate ring of a flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Edited:

[If G here is a simply connected semismple complex algebraic group.

1. A partial flag variety $G/P$ can be naturally embedded as a closed subset of $\prod_j \mathbb{P} (L(\omega_j)^*)$.
2. The multi-homogeneous coordinate ring of $G/P$ coming from that embedding is what I mean by "the coordinate ring".
3. \omega_j are the fundamental weights of $G$.
4. $P$ is a parabolic closed subgroup.
5. If $\Pi_J$ is the set of sums $\sum_j a_j \omega_j$, $a_j \in \mathbb{N}$, then it is well-known that $\mathbb{C}[G/P]$ is a $\Pi_J$ graded ring with natural G-mod structure.]

Now, $\mathbb{C}[G/P]$ is graded by $L(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is of the form $\sum_j a_j \omega_j$ and $a_j \in \mathbb{N}$ with the ordering
$$\mu \leq \lambda \text{ iff } \lambda - \mu \in \sum_j \mathbb{N} \omega_j. $$

If we know that $L(\mu_1) \cdot L(\mu_2) \cdot L(\mu_3) \cdot L(\mu_4) \subset L(\lambda)$ and $x_i \in L(\mu_i)$, when can we say that $x_1x_2+x_3x_4 \in L(\lambda)$?

Comment: I do not understand this question.  If $G$ equals $\textbf{SL}_{n+1}$ and $G/P$ equals projective $n$-space with its standard action of $\textbf{SL}_{n+1}$, then the coordinate ring is graded by nonnegative integers.  If the weights of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ are, respectively, $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\mu_3$ and $\mu_4$, then typically the element $x_1x_2+x_3x_4$ is inhomogeneous.  It is homogeneous if $\mu_1+\mu_2$ equals $\mu_3+\mu_4$, but then the correct graded piece is of degree $\mu_1+\mu_2=\mu_3+\mu_4$.

Comment: maybe my question is:

when can we decide that $x_1x_2+x_3x_4 \in L(\lambda)$.

Comment: By coordinate ring do you mean the Cox ring? Or the graded ring corresponding to powers of the anticanonical class? In any case your "well-known" description does not seem to involve anything about $P$. What are $\omega_j$? I think in the current form the question should be closed.

Comment: @F.H.A "maybe my question is: when can we decide that $x_1x_2+x_3x_4\in L(\lambda)$".  Will you please clarify precisely what your question is?  If you do not know what question you are asking, that makes it difficult for MO users to help.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger.  At least when $G$ is a simply connected, semisimple group and $P$ is a Borel $B$, then $G/B$ is indeed graded by the weight lattice of $G$, even the semigroup (the "dominant chamber") generated by the fundamental weights $\omega_j$ in the weight lattice.  I assume that this is what the OP has in mind.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger
0. Yes, G here is a simply connected semismple complex algebraic group.
1. A partial flag variety $G/P$ can be naturally embedded as a closed subset of $\prod_j \mathbb{P} (L(\omega_j)^*)$.
2. The multi-homogeneous coordinate ring of $G/P$ coming from that embedding is what I mean by "the coordinate ring".
3. \omega_j are the fundamental weights of $G$.
4. $P$ is a parabolic closed subgroup.
5. If $\Pi_J$ is the set of sums $\sum_j a_j \omega_j$, $a_j \in \mathbb{N}$.
6. It is WELL KNOWN that $\mathbb{C}[G/P]$ is a $\Pi_J$ graded ring with natural G-mod structure.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I think some of these explanations could make the question more understandable - consider editing it.